# How to create datatable with ajax and jquery from list without Entity Framework on ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create table with HTML Display with ASP.NET MVC.

Here is the sample

```html
@model IEnumerable
<Vitashopper.Models.Goods>

  <title>
    Master Goods Vitashopper
  </title>
  
  <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
  </p>

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductId)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BuyPrice)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SellPrice)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stock)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Remarks)
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BuyPrice)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellPrice)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remarks)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProductId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ProductId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", onclick = "return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');"
        })
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </table>
```

Here is the model that I'm using:

```php
public class Goods
{
  public int ProductId { get; set; }

  [DisplayName("Product Name")]
  public string ProductName { get; set; }

  public decimal BuyPrice { get; set; }
  public decimal SellPrice { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int Stock { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```php
public List < Goods > GetGoods() 
{
  connection();
  List < Goods > goodslist = new List < Goods > ();

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllGoods", con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  con.Open();
  sd.Fill(dt);
  con.Close();

  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    goodslist.Add(
      new Goods {
        ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ProductID"]),
          ProductName = Convert.ToString(dr["ProductName"]),
          BuyPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["BuyPrice"]),
          SellPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["SellPrice"]),
          Stock = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Stock"]),
          Description = Convert.ToString(dr["Description"]),
          Remarks = Convert.ToString(dr["Remarks"])
      });
  }

  return goodslist;
}
```

My question is it possible to migration this datatable to ajax & jQuery without Entity Framework? I keep searching but the problem solve with Entity Framework not using SQL Server database.

Expected output should be as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: ajax & jquery are client side technologies. entity framework is a back end technology. To work with a database you always need a back end technology. That may or may not use entity framework. You could write a database API in PHP and call it from ajax if you liked.

Comment: thanks for your advice. but currently I prefer using ASP for my website. I ever try PHP but its not recommend for my business application

Comment: I'm not suggesting you actually use PHP. I'm trying to highlight how this works. So go ahead and write an API in ASP.Net and call it using ajax. To not use entity framework You can use the approach described in the first part of this article. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/database-connectivity-with-and-without-entity-framework-in-mvc/ you might want to exaplin what reasons you have for not wanting to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try to implement this

```
<script>  
        $(document).ready(function () {  
            $("#demoGrid").DataTable({  
  
                "processing": true, // for show progress bar  
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side  
                "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)  
                "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once  
                "pageLength": 5,  
  
                "ajax": {  
                    "url": "/Demo/LoadData",  
                    "type": "POST",  
                    "datatype": "json"  
                },  
  
                "columnDefs":  
                [{  
                    "targets": [0],  
                    "visible": false,  
                    "searchable": false  
                },  
                {  
                    "targets": [7],  
                    "searchable": false,  
                    "orderable": false  
                },  
                {  
                    "targets": [8],  
                    "searchable": false,  
                    "orderable": false  
                },  
                {  
                    "targets": [9],  
                    "searchable": false,  
                    "orderable": false  
                }],  
  
                "columns": [  
                      { "data": "CustomerID", "name": "CustomerID", "autoWidth": true },  
                      { "data": "CompanyName", "name": "CompanyName", "autoWidth": true },  
                      { "data": "ContactName", "title": "ContactName", "name": "ContactName", "autoWidth": true },  
                      { "data": "ContactTitle", "name": "ContactTitle", "autoWidth": true },  
                      { "data": "City", "name": "City", "autoWidth": true },  
                      { "data": "PostalCode", "name": "PostalCode", "autoWidth": true },  
                      { "data": "Country", "name": "Country", "autoWidth": true },  
                      { "data": "Phone", "name": "Phone", "title": "Status", "autoWidth": true },  
                      {  
                          "render": function (data, type, full, meta)  
                          { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/Demo/Edit/' + full.CustomerID + '">Edit</a>'; }  
                      },  
                       {  
                           data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {  
                               return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.CustomerID + "'); >Delete</a>";  
                           }  
                       },  
  
                ]  
  
            });  
        });  
    </script>
```

Reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: maybe this article can help to https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/55772/how-can-i-get-asp-net-c-to-load-ajax-json-data-returned-from-the-server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).